# Solving a simple Ax=b system in parallel with PETSc

Tags: petsc, matrix

I am new to the PETSc package.

I have a ~4000x4000 matrix A in matrix-market format and I want to get PETSc to solve this using multiple processors.

I know how to solve the system on a single processor, but I don't know how
to distribute the matrix and vectors among different processors.

Is there a simple set of instructions to do this?

Answer (score 14):

Matrix Market is a terrible format for reading in parallel, therefore it is better to preprocess to a better parallel format. Your matrix size is extremely small so performance is not an issue, but the easiest and most general thing is to use Python or Matlab/Octave to write the Matrix Market file in PETSc binary format, which can be read efficiently in parallel using [`MatLoad()`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/Mat/MatLoad.html). For example, you can use this Python code for the preprocessing (add `$PETSC_DIR/bin/pythonscripts` to your `PYTHONPATH`)

```
import scipy.io, PetscBinaryIO
A = scipy.io.mmread('thematrix.mtx')
PetscBinaryIO.PetscBinaryIO().writeMatSciPy(open('petscmatrix','w'), A)
```

You can also write a vector to the file at this time. If you just want to read and solve the system, you can use [`src/ksp/ksp/examples/tutorials/ex10.c`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/src/ksp/ksp/examples/tutorials/ex10.c.html) (with the option `-f petscmatrix` to read the binary file you just wrote).

In a real application, you should avoid a workflow that involves writing files to disk in any format. It is much better to assemble the matrix in parallel using a domain-decomposed representation of the problem. Most examples in PETSc are written this way.